# WebRequest toward inactive server freeze the Application, Visual Studio and the Desktop?

Tags: c#, wpf

Trying to run a never-ending task starting once the Window is loaded, which repeat itself 1 second delay after it's completion of refreshing the UI.

Until the server is available and it is receiving data everything seems fine.
Yet - at the moment the application start but the server is not available I got :

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.Net.Requests.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Net.Http.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Net.Http.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

and the application freeze, Visual Studio freeze, and the Desktop freeze. The only possible out of the situation is to kill the application with Task Manager.

```
private async void OnLoadComplete( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    //..       
    startTheDataExtraction();
    //..
}

private async Task startTheDataExtraction()
{
    Task<JObject> task = Task<JObject>.Run( async () =>
    {
        JObject r = new JObject();
        try
        {
            r = await getControllersData();
            Debug.WriteLine( 3 );
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {

        }
         
        return r;
        
    });            
    
    Task UITask = task.ContinueWith( ( ret ) =>
    {
        // refresh the UI
        var jO = ret.Result;
        
        try
        {
            if( jO != null )
            {
                if( jO.HasValues )
                {                                   
                    refreshTheUI( jO );                            
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // problematic execution or data 
            }               
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {

        }
        
        // reshedule next interaction
        resheduleDataExtraction();
    }, 
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() );            
}

public void resheduleDataExtraction()
{
    Task.Delay( 1000 ).ContinueWith( async (d) =>
    {
        await startTheDataExtraction();
    } );

}

public static async Task<JObject> getControllersData()
{
    JObject r = new JObject();

    JObject request = new JObject();

    request.Add( "GUIDS", new JArray( GUIDS.ToArray() ) );

    try
    {
        r = await postJSON( request, "Readings" );

        if( r != null )// there is a data
        {                   
            lastSuccessfulDataExtraction = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
    }

    return r;
}

public static async Task<JObject> postJSON( JObject jo, string APIProcedure )
{
    JObject r = new JObject();
    
    jo.Add( "sessionID", sessionID );
    jo.Add( "version", Globals.version );

    try
    {
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create( APIUrl( APIProcedure ) );
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        using( Stream postStream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync() )
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( jo.ToString() );
            await postStream.WriteAsync( byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length );
            await postStream.FlushAsync();
        }
        try
        {
            string Response;
            using( var response = ( HttpWebResponse ) await webRequest.GetResponseAsync() )
            using( Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream() )
            using( StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader( streamResponse ) )
            {
                Response = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            if( Response == "" )
            {
                //show some error msg to the user        
                Debug.WriteLine( "ERROR" );

            }
            else
            {
                //Your response will be available in "Response" 
                //Debug.WriteLine( Response );
                r = JObject.Parse( Response );
            }
        }
        catch( WebException )
        {
            //error    
        }
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        Debug.WriteLine( "x" );
    }
    return r;
}
```

- What is causing the freeze, and how to fix it ?

PS: .NET 6.0 project

PS : Created a repo with demo project https://github.com/YordanYanakiev/WFPRequestIssue

PS : Seems like the issue is in the line **webRequest.GetResponse();** either **await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();** both throwing exception directly, without possible way to continue the execution ( it does not return null, instead just crash the thread )

Comment: Tried also with HttClient, WebRequest and HttpWebRequest - the freezing goes with any of them. ( if this helps :| )

Comment: PS : Seems like .NET 7 and .NET 8 acting a bit better and at least not completely freezing anything, but yet it could be random occurrence.